# What is Poincare's lemma applied to the coulomb gauge?

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, manifolds, electromagnetism

### Background:

I have now studied up on differential forms.

Here are some outcomes of the study

- Understand  $\omega:T_p \mathbb{R^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
- Can integrate m-forms
- Can do derivatives of forms
- Understand Hodge

I have several electromagnetism courses under my belt(not bragging just giving background). My count is 3. ( soon to be 4)

- I can write maxwell's equations in terms of forms

### Arena

The transverse gauge (Coulomb gauge).

Going from the gauge condition $\nabla \cdot A = 0$ to writing an expression for A. On a good day, I can do this using physical arguments and basic PDE theory.

Vocabulary: I have not read up on closed forms but it seems they are forms whose derivative is zero, and an exact form is one whose derivative is another form.

### #Question

What is the simplest way to state Poincare Lemma such that I can apply it computationally to the coulomb gauge?

I can for example now almost recite the lemma but I don't understand what it means. I think it goes something like
"~every closed differential form is locally exact" I don't know how this says anything about the vector potential A.

---

Below is my old attempt at asking the question. I have left it here for historical purposes.

---

I am trying to understand gauge fixing.

I want to believe that the [coulomb gauge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_fixing#Coulomb_gauge) is defined by the gauge condition: $\nabla \cdot A = 0$

Now all I have to do is try to solve for A.

It seems the standard physics trick is to start by making a connection with the magnetic field $B$ in terms of the vector potential. So $B = \nabla \times A$. From here one substitutes $B = \nabla \times A$ into  $\nabla \times B = \mu J$ to get a Poisson vector potential.

The next trick is to make physical arguments about sources (solving by greens function) and then write down the standard solution.

$A = \frac{\mu}{4 \pi} \int \int \int \frac{J}{|r-r'|} dV$

How is this done to arrive at the standard expression that one gets?

My understanding is that there is a more direct way this is done in mathematics starting with $\nabla \cdot A =0$ there are some lemmas: like [Poincare lemma](http://www.math.toronto.edu/campesat/ens/1920/poincare.pdf) that magically take you to the standard solution directly. For example, see the application to Electromagnetism in this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_and_exact_differential_forms#Application_in_electrodynamics) The only problem is that I've looked at this lemma for a while now and I am having some trouble with it.

Comment: What is the "standard expression" that one gets, and is it not on the same wiki page?

Comment: The standard expression is indeed on the same wiki page. I am just having trouble getting there from the gauge condition.

Comment: @Randall I have now modified the question and added required context